# ListviewItem Style alternate Background WindowsPhone 8.1

Tags: background, windows-phone-8.1, converters

I would appreciate if could help me. I've searched the whole days and still struggling with that issue. I want to have alternate backgroundcolor in my ListView.
Sorry for the Long text. Maybe you could help. Thanks a lot...

P.S.: Sorry for the bad XAML LAyout... it was impossible to get it nice (any tricks for the future?)

1.) Resource Dictionary in a seperate file

```
ResourceDictionary xmlns:namespc="clr-namespace:GANTERportal"
Style x:Key="ModulesListViewItemStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem"
    Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,10,0,10"
    Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"
    Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"
    Setter Property="Background"
        Setter.Value
        Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"
        Converter="{StaticResource listview_bg_Converter}"
        Setter.Value      
    Setter
Style
```

2.) Application XAML

```
Application.Resources>
    ResourceDictionary>
        ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        ResourceDictionary Source="styles/Styles.xaml"
            ResourceDictionary
                namespc:listview_bg_Converter x:Key="listview_bg_Converter"
            ResourceDictionary
        ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries
    ResourceDictionary
Application.Resources
```

3.) IValueConverter

```
public class listview_bg_Converter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)value;
        ListView listView = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item) as ListView;

        int index = listView.Items.IndexOf(item);

        SolidColorBrush a;

        if (index % 2 == 0)
        return a = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Turquoise);
        else
        return a = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Violet);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

4.) MainPage.xaml

```
<ListView x:Name="listview_modules"
         ItemSource="{Binding}"
         SelectionChanged="listview_modules_SelectionChanged"
         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ModulesListViewItemStyle}"
         >
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel x:Name="stackpanel_modules"
            TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource MyTextStyle}">
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

5.) Error Message when Starting App

> Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Setter' to type
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewItem'.

Comment: To display a `code` block within a list, you need to indent the code with 2 tabs/8 spaces. So, just copy-paste the xaml and make sure each line has at least 2 tabs/8 spaces at the beginning. I think that should work.

Comment: @thezapper think about binding your listview_bg_Converter  to the background color of the `stackpanel`.  Plus can you fix your XAML, I can't make out what is going on.

Comment: thanks yasen. great work. I'll do it myself next time

Comment: Chubosaurus: I'm not binding the converter to the stackpanel. I have a Style for the Textblock only. I have set the style of ItemContainer to Modules ModulesListViewItemStyle. In that style I'm binding my converter to the baclground. This was so far what I've seen in the net... By the value in my IValueConverter is not the ListViewItem, but the Setter?!

Comment: Chubosaurus: If I'm binding the converter to the stackpanel, how do I get the Index of the row to alternate the color?! Thanks for any advise